# How to use KeyDragZoom with GMAP3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, keydragzoom

The documentation shows - http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/keydragzoom/1.0/docs/examples.html

```
     function init(){
      var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 13, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.2903, -123.1294), 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
       };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); 
      map.enableKeyDragZoom({
            boxStyle: {
              border: "thick dashed black",
              backgroundColor: "red",
              opacity: 0.5
            },
            paneStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "gray",
              opacity: 0.2
            }
      });
    }
```

but because i am using gmap3 im not sure how to implement? 
here is my code to init the map

```
     $('#dispatcher').gmap3(
      {action: 'init',
        options:{
          center:[53.9783997, -1.5666347],
          zoom:6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
          },
          navigationControl: true,
          scrollwheel: true,
          streetViewControl: true
        }
      }
```

any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#dispatcher').gmap3({action:'get'}).enableKeyDragZoom({
            boxStyle: {
              border: "thick dashed black",
              backgroundColor: "red",
              opacity: 0.5
            },
            paneStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "gray",
              opacity: 0.2
            }
      });
```

`.gmap3({action:'get'})` returns `google.maps.Map` object. So you can perform any actions on it,that `google.maps.Map` object can do, included `enableKeyDragZoom` action.

Comment: cheers, tried it but didn't work :( maybe its just not compatible?

Comment: @VinceLowe Try with `{action:'get'}`.I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, or you also can use the callback function from "init" wich include the map:

```
    callback: function(map){
       map.enableKeyDragZoom({
        boxStyle: {
          border: "thick dashed black",
          backgroundColor: "red",
          opacity: 0.5
        },
        paneStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "gray",
          opacity: 0.2
                }
        });
    }
```